# Are prime triplets & prime triples the same?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, definition

Prime Triplet & Prime Triple
Are they two different things?

A prime triple is three consecutive primes, such that the first and the last differ by six.
prime-triplets must have the form
$(p, p+2, p+6)$ e.g.  $(5,7,11)$, $(p, p+4, p+6)$ e.g.  $(7,11,13)$

A prime triplet is a set of three prime numbers which form an arithmetic sequence with a common difference of two.

I read these two statements\

- there are no prime triplet other than $(3, 5, 7)$\
- there is no other prime triple then $(3,5,7)$

I'm confused. Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: First... an ordered triple is just an ordered sequence of three numbers, notated by being enclosed in parentheses with commas separating them.  $(1,2,3)$ is an example of a triple.  $(2,10,20)$ is another, and so on...  We can talk about triples who are of a particular form where other entries are written in relation to each other... $(x,x+2,x+4)$ for instance which would include examples such as $(1,3,5),(2,4,6),(10,12,14),(13,15,17)$ and so on...  As another example, $(x,x+2,x+6)$ which would include examples like $(1,3,7)$ and $(5,7,11)$ and so on...

Comment: The statement you are citing is saying that there is one and only one triple whose entries are all prime of the form $(p,p+2,p+4)$ and that would be the triple $(3,5,7)$ itself (*since among $x,x+2,x+4$ at least one must be a multiple of $3$*).  There do exist other triples whose entries are all prime of different forms, the most interesting of which are those of the form $(p,p+2,p+6)$ or $(p,p+4,p+6)$ so that the primes are as close together as possible while remaining non-trivial.  What these triples are named... "prime triples" or "prime triplets" doesn't really matter.

Comment: @JMoravitz Excellent comments , I think this is worth an answer. I think, the context is sufficient.

Comment: Note that tuples probably giving infinite many prime-tuples are called "admissable" , usually it is also demanded that we cannot add another entry inside without destroying this property. We do not know that such an admissable tuple produces infinite many tuples with all entries prime numbers, but this is conjectured to be the case.

Comment: So there are more than 1 prime triplets, just in a different form? how should I answer this question; Enter a prime triplet, where each member of the triplet is less than 100, just (3,5,7)?  I entered (5,7,11) and it was incorrect.

Comment: @Annai My answer would be in this case (triples) that there are two kinds of prime constellations (this is the usual terminology) : $(n,n+2,n+6)$ and $(n,n+4,n+6)$ both probably producing infinite many triples consisting only of prime numbers. You can of course also call those objects just prime triples, makes not really a difference.

Comment: $(n,n+2,n+4)$ produces only one prime triple since one of the numbers must be divisible by $3$, namely $(3,5,7)$ so I think this should not be mentioned.

Comment: The key said (3,5,7) is the correct answer. so my answer (5,7,11) is wrong :(

Comment: prime triplet as an extension of twin primes as described in your question ($n,n+2,n+4$) is , I think , not a very common terminology.

Comment: Thank you both :)